# PubNub issue in node 12

Tags: node.js, pubnub

Has anyone tried running pubnub sdk in node 12.x?
On their docs, found that it supports till node 8. Link - https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/supported-platforms

Does anyone have any updates whether they are going to add support for 12 soon or any possible workaround?

Answer (score 3):

## PubNub Node Versions Support

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. We are building in travis on node 12 with success, we just need to [update the supported versions](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/nodejs-javascript/supported-platforms). We will likely update it when when do a new release (4.27.2) today.

Comment: Okay, Thanks @Craig!